# Doctrine fails to persist on record delete

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

when user want's to delete record (language in my case) I want to prevent deletion of record (language) if it's referenced in any other table in system.

Problem is that language (record) in my case gets deleted even if it's referenced in any other table. I checked my relationships in MySQL workbench and it says that on DELETE and ON UPDATE it RESTRICT action but for some reason Doctrine/Symfony allows delete of same field.

Does someone knows where is the problem?

Here are Entity setup:

```
/**
     *  Many drivers have Many langauges (OWNING SIDE)
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Language", inversedBy="language", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bus_drivers_languages",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_driver_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="languages_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     **/

    private $languages;



/**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="BusDriver", mappedBy="languages", cascade={"persist"})
     */
     protected $language;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce it at the database level (that way you maintain consistency throughout your application)...

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
ADD CONSTRAINT `constraint_name`
FOREIGN KEY (`column_list`)
REFERENCES `referenced_table` (`referenced_column_list`);
```